# How to disable access request in SharePoint Online using CSOM

Tags: powershell, permissions, csom

I am trying to disable access request using PowerShell CSOM.
But when i try to set RequestAccessEmail to "", it does not work if the first radio button is checked. It will work only if the second radio button is checked.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

here is the script:

```
$SiteUrl = "https://<TenantName>.sharepoint.com/sites/<Sitename>"  
$UserName = "admin@<TenantName>..onmicrosoft.com"  
$Password ="password"
$loadInfo1 = [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SharePoint.Client") 
$loadInfo2 = [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime")
$loadInfo3 = [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.UserProfiles")
#$sstr = ConvertTo-SecureString -string $AdminPass -AsPlainText -Force
$Securepass = ConvertTo-SecureString $Password -AsPlainText -Force
$context = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($SiteUrl)
$context.Credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($UserName,$Securepass)
$Web = $context.Web
$AllProperties=$Web.AllProperties
$context.Load($Web)
$context.Load($AllProperties)
$context.ExecuteQuery()
$Web.MembersCanShare=$false
$web.Update();
$web.Context.ExecuteQuery()
$AssociatedMember=$web.AssociatedMemberGroup
$context.Load($AssociatedMember)
$context.ExecuteQuery()
$web.AssociatedMemberGroup.AllowMembersEditMembership = $false
$web.AssociatedMemberGroup.Update();
$web.Context.ExecuteQuery()
```

You need to install CSOM module Version 16.1.4727.1200 and above to use this.

*Hope it helps!*

Comment: This approach doesnt work, have to tried this scenario, where the radio button is defaulted to the Owners group and you are disabling the access request